# Global scope prop in functional react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, react-native-sound

I am using `react-native-sound` for audio in this component and want to play from a url file that is passed to the component. The problem is that if the var audio is declared inside the functional component then each time the component renders the variable is created again and this plays the sound file as a new instance and we have same sound playing multiple times on top of each other.

```
import Sound from "react-native-sound"

var audio = new Sound.. //Works if declared here but cant's pass url prop

const SoundPlayer: FC<SoundProps> = ({ url }) => {
    const [playing, setPlaying] = useState<boolean | null>(null)

    var audio = new Sound(url, null, (error) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log("failed to load the sound", error)
            return
        }
    })
```

If I move the var audio outside / above the functional component as a global variable it works fine but then I can not pass the component prop aka `url` to it as the variable is out of the function component scope. How can I pass a prop that keeps reference and does not recreate on each render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using useEffect:

```
const audioRef = useRef(null);
const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
   // This will be triggered only once when the component is mounted
   audioRef.current = new Sound(url, null, (error) => {
      if(error) {
         // Here you can implement some retry policy if there was some error loading the sound
         return;
      }

      setDuration(Math.trunc(audioRef.current.getDuration())); 
   });

   return = () => {
     // This will be triggered on component is unmounted
     audioRef.current.release();
   }
}, [audioRef, setDuration]);
```

P.D.: This code was written on the fly, so further modifications might be needed

Comment: When with this but added }, [audioRef] in the useEffect dependency array.

Comment: Tried also to add setDuration(Math.trunc(audioRef.current.getDuration())) inside the useEffect after the new Sound is created but for some reason I can not get the duration of the song gets the value -1.

Comment: @PatrikRikama-Hinnenberg are you trying to get the duration in the callback method on Sound creation instance after the sound is loaded without any error? Or just in the line after  audioRef.current = new Sound(...)?

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
  if (audioRef.current === null) {
   audioRef.current = new Sound(url, null, (error) => {
    if (error) {
     console.log("failed to load the sound", error)
     return
    }
   })
  }
  audioRef.current.setVolume(1)
  setDuration(Math.trunc(audioRef.current.getDuration()))
  return () => {
   audioRef.current.release()
  }
 }, [audioRef])`

Comment: in same useEffect after new Sound.

Comment: In that moment the sound is probably not loaded yet. I'll update my answer with the example.

Comment: Spot on, thanks @Stepan Nikulenko

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct use case for `useRef` (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

```js
import Sound from "react-native-sound"

const SoundPlayer: FC<SoundProps> = ({ url }) => {
    const audioRef = useRef(null); 
    const [playing, setPlaying] = useState<boolean | null>(null)

  // use useEffect to hook on mounted
   useEffect(() => {
    if(audioRef.current === null) {
      audioRef.current = new Sound(url, null, (error) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log("failed to load the sound", error)
            return
        }
      })
    }
   }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
import Sound from "react-native-sound"

var audio;

const SoundPlayer: FC<SoundProps> = ({ url }) => {
    const [playing, setPlaying] = useState<boolean | null>(null)
    
    useEffect(() => {
      audio = new Sound(url, null, (error) => {
          if (error) {
              console.log("failed to load the sound", error)
              return
          }
      })
    }, [url]);
```

Comment: Interesting. I thought still that this mutates the variable outside the functional component and thus make it no longer functional instead a stateful component.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap in `useEffect` and have dependency array as [] will run only once or [url] to update when url updates

```
const [audio, setAudio] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
  var ado = new Sound(url, null, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("failed to load the sound", error);
      return;
    }
  });
  setAudio(ado);
}, [url]);
```

Comment: Simple as that. Is there some negative sides to this vs useRef solution ?